# Same message is being received by multiple receivers using event hubs

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-eventhub

An event hub is created in Azure. This event hub has $default consumer group. It has 32 partitions.

There is one sender to this event hub which sends messages at some particular frequency. Now there are multiple receivers to this event hub. The code to send and receive is written in Python exactly as per [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send?tabs=passwordless%2Croles-azure-portal). This receiver Python script is running in 5 different VMs.

The expectation is, only one of the receiver should receive the message and process it. But it is observed that more than one receiver is receiving the same message.

I read that if checkpointing is not done, this might happen. But in the sample code, I see that the checkpointing is done. What else is missing? Or is my expectation wrong?

PS : People who have worked previously have started using event hubs and entire infrastructure and code is around event hubs. It's kind of difficult to move away from event hubs now. So I plan to stick with event-hubs for now.

Comment: Are all messages received multiple times?

Comment: @PeterBons, Not all . If I have to say it in percentage wise , then may be 10% of messages are getting received multiple times.

Comment: What process hosts the receivers? Could it be that receivers are killed/terminated somehow unexpectedly?

Comment: @PeterBons , How do I check if the receivers are getting killed or terminated ?

Comment: This can happen during normal activity when partition ownership moves between consumers, such as when scaling up/down.  It can also happen during error scenarios or when a node being overloaded, and load balancing is not running on its schedule.   The old owner can have a batch in memory that it is processing while the new owner takes over and starts from the most recent checkpoint.  The old owner isn't aware of the change until the next time it attempts to read from the partition.   Event Hubs has an at-least-once delivery guarantee, and your application should be idempotent when processing.

Comment: @JesseSquire , Thanks so much for the reply. Can you please elaborate on what it means by "your application should be idempotent when processing". Can you share some examples if possible please ?

Comment: Your application needs to ensure that it can detect duplicate events, if your system is sensitive to them, and not process them.  It's not a topic that can really be discussed in SO comments, and it will look quite different for each application.  Generally, it involves your publisher setting a unique MessageId for an event and your consumer(s) tracking which ids have been processed.

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/compare-messaging-services#azure-event-hubs) provides "at least once" delivery at a large scale, which means duplicates may occur. While normally you shouldn't experience any, there are certain cases when it might happen. Some of them, but not limited to, include:

**Multiple receivers on a partition within a consumer group.** In this scenario, all readers receive all the events of the partition. This probably isn't relevant to your situation, as you are using the SDK, which takes care of this.

**Receiver crash before committing the checkpoint.** Checkpointing is usually performed at regular intervals. If the processor crashes before marking the position of the last successfully processed event, a new processor will start from the last committed checkpoint. This may result in picking up some events that were processed by the first consumer before it crashed. This is likely to be your case.

Ideally, you should design your downstream system idempotent. If that's too difficult or is not feasible, consider strategies for deduplicating the events.

Comment: The clarify, the SDK only ensures a single active reader per partition when a checkpoint store is provided to the consumer or when callers explicitly request exclusive access.  Other than those scenarios, multiple consumers using the same consumer group can read concurrently from a single partition.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I'm checkpointing as soon as a message is received. Also how do I check if the processor is crashing before checkpointing. Is there any specific error message to look out for?

Comment: Your error handler is pinged for any internal issues with the processor - such as when a specific partition experiences an issue and needs to be restarted.